# why does Logger.Output acquire mutex before checking Lshortfile/Llongfile flag

Tags: go

In Go's implementation of `(l *Logger) Output`, why acquire mutex before  `if l.flag&(Lshortfile|Llongfile) != 0 {`?

```
func (l *Logger) Output(calldepth int, s string) error {
    now := time.Now() // get this early.
    var file string
    var line int
    l.mu.Lock()
    defer l.mu.Unlock()
    if l.flag&(Lshortfile|Llongfile) != 0 {
        // Release lock while getting caller info - it's expensive.
        l.mu.Unlock()
        var ok bool
        _, file, line, ok = runtime.Caller(calldepth)
        if !ok {
            file = "???"
            line = 0
        }
        l.mu.Lock()
    }
    l.buf = l.buf[:0]
    l.formatHeader(&l.buf, now, file, line)
    l.buf = append(l.buf, s...)
    if len(s) == 0 || s[len(s)-1] != '\n' {
        l.buf = append(l.buf, '\n')
    }
    _, err := l.out.Write(l.buf)
    return err
}
```

what about this?

```
func (l *Logger) Output(calldepth int, s string) error {
    now := time.Now() // get this early.
    var file string
    var line int
    if l.flag&(Lshortfile|Llongfile) != 0 {
        var ok bool
        _, file, line, ok = runtime.Caller(calldepth)
        if !ok {
            file = "???"
            line = 0
        }
    }
    // acquire mutex here, avoid aquire mutex twice. 
    l.mu.Lock()
    defer l.mu.Unlock()
    l.buf = l.buf[:0]
    l.formatHeader(&l.buf, now, file, line)
    l.buf = append(l.buf, s...)
    if len(s) == 0 || s[len(s)-1] != '\n' {
        l.buf = append(l.buf, '\n')
    }
    _, err := l.out.Write(l.buf)
    return err
}
```

Comment: To make the logger safe for concurrent use as explained in the documentation which you always should read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Logger.flag](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go?s=2529:2843#L42) is the field protected by a mutex, not the [constants](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#pkg-constants).

[log.Logger](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger) has a [SetFlags](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#Logger.SetFlags) method that can be called at any time from any goroutine. This method is implemented as:

```
// SetFlags sets the output flags for the logger.
// The flag bits are Ldate, Ltime, and so on.
func (l *Logger) SetFlags(flag int) {
    l.mu.Lock()
    defer l.mu.Unlock()
    l.flag = flag
}
```

The documentation itself make it clear that a logger is safe for concurrent use:

> A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; ...

To ensure this guarantee, any field of `Logger` that can be modified **must be synchronized**. If you access `l.flag` without proper synchronization, you are introducing a race condition.